# Haskell (Aeson) : How to construct a record from JSON with additional values

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I have a record that I want to construct with some values from a JSON string as well as some additionally provided values.

For example - given the following record:

```
data MyRecord = MyRecord { a :: String, b :: Int, c :: String }
```

I want do define a function:

```
createMyRecord :: String -> String -> Maybe MyRecord
createMyRecord json cValue = ???
```

Which I want to be able to call like so:

```
createMyRecord "{\"a\": \"a value\", \"b\": 100}" "c value"
```

Currently, I'm doing this by use Aeson to create the record with defaults (i.e. empty strings and zeros) for the values which don't come from the JSON. I then create a new version of the record with the other fields updated. Something like this:

```
instance FromJSON MyRecord where
    parseJSON = withObject "MyRecord" $ \o -> do
        valueA <- o .: "a"
        valueB <- o .: "b"
        return MyRecord { a = valueA, b = valueB, c = "" }

createMyRecord :: String -> String -> Maybe MyRecord
createMyRecord json cValue =
    Aeson.decode json <$> (\r -> r { c = cValue })
```

This feels a bit cumbersome - I'd like to create the record in one go with all the values, rather than filling them in step by step. Is there a nicer way to do this with Aeson (I'm open to other libraries also) that anyone can recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to build `parseJSON`? It doesn't have to be `parseJSON`...

```
abParser :: String -> Value -> Parser MyRecord
abParser valueC = withObject "MyRecord" $ \o -> do
    valueA <- o .: "a"
    valueB <- o .: "b"
    return MyRecord { a = valueA, b = valueB, c = valueC }

createMyRecord :: ByteString -> String -> Maybe MyRecord
createMyRecord json valueC = decode json >>= parseMaybe (abParser valueC)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I knew there was a simple solution but was struggling to work it out.